# How to write integration test for Play Framework application to see if image is loaded?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I would like to write integration test which checks if image actually loads in Play Framework application page. Image is **generated** by application itself and may fail if invalid route is specified as *src* value. 
Is there an easy way to do that using browser test?

```scala
  @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
  class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {

      "display image in frontpage" in new WithBrowser {

        browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)

        // what should be coded here to test if image in <img id="mug_image" > 
        // was loaded    

      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: if you are going to the src of the image, can you check the size of the response as a proxy?

Comment: @2manyprojects is this code what you mean? `val img = browser.$("#mug_image") val imageUrl = img.getAttribute("src") val response: Response = Helpers.await(WS.url(imageUrl).get()) response.status must equalTo(OK) response.getAHCResponse.getContentType must equalTo("image/png") response.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes.size must beGreaterThan(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test seems to work for me:

```scala
"should show image in frontpage" in new WithBrowser {
  browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)
  val img = browser.$("#mug_image")
  val imageUrl = img.getAttribute("src")
  val response: Response = Helpers.await(WS.url(imageUrl).get())

  response.status must equalTo(OK)
  response.getAHCResponse.getContentType must equalTo("image/png")
  response.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes.size must beGreaterThan(0)
}
```